# R wireframe() wrong colorbar using lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I try to plot a transect using `wireframe()` with `lattice`

the colorbar is wrong

```
  require(marmap)
  require(lattice) 

     Bathy2 <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = 30, lon2 = 47,
                               lat1 = -12, lat2 = -28, resolution = 2)
#plot of the area + transect
     plot(Bathy2, image=TRUE, land = TRUE, lwd = 0.03,
             bpal = list(c(0,max(Bathy2), greys), c(min(Bathy2), 0, blues)))
     belt3 <- get.box(Bathy2, x1 = 34, x2 = 46, y1 = -20, y2 =  -20, width = 3, col = "red")

#3Dplot of the transect
       wireframe(belt3, shade = T, zoom = 1.1,
                  aspect = c(1/4, 0.1),
                  screen = list(z = -60, x = -55),
                  par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "white")),
                  par.box = c(col =rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
                  xlab="", colorkey = TRUE)
```

what I obtain is a pink colorbar
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [explained here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/wireframe-shade-T-colorkey-td836790.html), with `shade = TRUE`:

> the SAME Z-VALUE CAN HAVE DIFFERENT COLORS depending on the 
>   orientation of the facet with respect to the viewing direction and the 
>   light source. So, a colorkey DOES NOT MAKE SENSE.

So I suggest using `drape = TRUE` instead:

```
# 3Dplot of the transect
wireframe(belt3, drape = TRUE, zoom = 1.1,
          aspect = c(1/4, 0.1),
          screen = list(z = -60, x = -55),
          par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "white")),
          par.box = c(col =rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
          xlab="", colorkey = TRUE, lwd = 0.2)
```

[image]

You can also define your own color palette. Just check `?wireframe`.